# Cannot get video duration while calling YT video API

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I call YT search API, and then I get the full data for each video result (Video API).

However, I cannot get the each video duration.

I get an undefined error:

```
  var videoResultsFullData = YouTube.Videos.list('id,snippet', { id : searchResults.map(item => item.id.videoId)})
    var popularChannelIds = YouTube.Channels.list('id,snippet, statistics', {
         id: resultsParentChannelIds
    }).items.filter(ch => ch.statistics.subscriberCount > sh.getRange("D24").getValue() ).map(channel => channel.id);
   
    // .filter(video => popularChannelIds.includes(item.id.channelId));

    var videoPopularResultsFullData = 
    videoResultsFullData.getItems()
    .filter(video => popularChannelIds.includes(video.snippet.channelId));
// };


var range = 3;
for (var i in videoPopularResultsFullData) {
    var item = videoPopularResultsFullData[i];
    var temp = item.getContentDetails().duration;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in your situation, it is required to include `contentDetails` to `part`. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var videoResultsFullData = YouTube.Videos.list('id,snippet', { id : searchResults.map(item => item.id.videoId)})
```

#### To:

```
var videoResultsFullData = YouTube.Videos.list('id,snippet,contentDetails', { id : searchResults.map(item => item.id.videoId)})
```

Or, you can also use `part` as an array as follows.

```
var videoResultsFullData = YouTube.Videos.list(["id","snippet","contentDetails"], { id : searchResults.map(item => item.id.videoId)})
```

#### Reference:

- [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)